# How to change active tab using function.?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here I am Trying to change tab with `if else statement`. When a variable try to over a limit the active tab should be changed. I have little code below.

```
<ul class="tab1">
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" type="button" class="tablinks" onclick="changeTab(event, 'home'), home()" id="defaultOpen">English Language <img src="assets/images/infoico.png" width="20" height="20"></a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" type="button" class="tablinks" onclick="changeTab(event, 'tab1'), tab1()">Quantitative Aptitude <img src="assets/images/infoico.png" width="20" height="20"></a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" type="button" class="tablinks" onclick="changeTab(event, 'tab2'), tab2()">Logical Reasoning <img src="assets/images/infoico.png" width="20" height="20"></a></li>
</ul>
<input type="button" name="catab" value="CheckTab" onclick="return checktabs()"/>
```

JavaScript function, I'm working with this.

```
<script>
        function changeTab(evt, cityName) {
            var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
            tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
            for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
                tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
            for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
                tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
            }
            document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
            evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
        }

        // Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
        document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
    </script>
```

I am trying below code to work with this tabs but didn't get success.

```
<script>
    function checktabs(){
       var j = 0;
        if(j == 3){
          changeTab(event, 'tab1');
        }
        j++;
    }
</script>

<script>
     function home(e){
        e.preventDefault();
      }
      function tab1(e){
        e.preventDefault();
      }
      function tab2(e){
        e.preventDefault();
      }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you copy-pasted your code into Stack Overflow as above, I see you have a few problems.  Your code above:

```
<script>
    function checktabs(){
       var j = 0;
        if(j == 3){
          changeTab(event, 'tab1');
        }
        j++;
    }
</script>
      function home(e){
        e.preventDefault();
      }
      function tab1(e){
        e.preventDefault();
      }
      function tab2(e){
        e.preventDefault();
      }
<script>

</script>
```

...should have no close-script, functions, open-script, close-script structure, should be like this:

```
<script>
    function checktabs(){
        var j = 0;
        if(j == 3){
            changeTab(event, 'tab1');
        }
        j++;
    }
    function home(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    function tab1(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    function tab2(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
</script>
```

Second, the j variable you are using has been defined with "var j = 0;" within the function checktabs(). When the function returns, j will not exist, and next time it'll be back to 0. Defining it outside the function will help, like this:

```
var j = 0;
function checktabs(){
    if(j == 3){
        changeTab(event, 'tab1');
    }
    j++;
}
```

That should solve your problem.

Comment: I just separate my code from whole code so I forgot to write it in `<script>`. This code can't able to change my active class of ul. I don't know what is happening with this code.

Comment: Your ul li do not have id properties, except the first one 'defaultOpen'.  You could change your checktabs to include something like 

document.getElementById("tab1").click();

Comment: Firstly when I write `changeTab(event, 'tab1');` code. It's not giving me any output like any simple alert or message. With `document.getElement` not working for me.

Comment: You could always add in your own alert code wherever you want.